# Failed to resolve endpoint: No component found with scheme: servlet

Tags: java, apache-camel, osgi

i am trying to register camel servlet in OSGI,but geeting below error while startup

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: servlet://router due to: No component found with scheme: servlet
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:729)
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:80)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.resolveEndpoint(RouteDefinition.java:219)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:112)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:118)
    at org.apache.camel.model.FromDefinition.resolveEndpoint(FromDefinition.java:69)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.getEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:94)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1278)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:204)
```

servlet registration ,

```
<bean id="CamelServlet" class="org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet" scope="prototype"/>

<osgi:service ref="CamelServlet">
    <osgi:interfaces>
        <value>javax.servlet.Servlet</value>
        <value>org.apache.camel.component.http.CamelServlet</value>
    </osgi:interfaces>
    <osgi:service-properties>
       <entry key="osgi.http.whiteboard.servlet.pattern" value="/camel/*"/>
        <entry key="osgi.http.whiteboard.context.select" value="(osgi.http.whiteboard.context.name=org.osgi.service.http.default)" />            
        <entry key="matchOnUriPrefix" value="true" />
        <entry key="servlet-name" value="CamelServlet"/>
    </osgi:service-properties>
</osgi:service>
```

and my camel context are as below

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route id="route1">
            <from uri="servlet:router"/>
            <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
            <transform>
        <simple>${body.toUpperCase()}</simple>
         </transform>
       <!-- and then print to the console -->
        <to uri="stream:out"/>
        </route>
</camelContext>
```

using camel 2.19.1 version and all required bundles are present in classpath

Comment: Are you sure that `camel-servlet` is present on the classpath?

Comment: @mgyongyosi:i have beow jars in my classpath org.apache.camel.camel-servlet-2.19.1
org.apache.camel.camel-spring-2.19.1,
org.apache.camel.camel-http-common-2.19.1,
org.apache.camel.camel-http-2.19.1,
org.apache.camel.camel-core-2.19.1

Comment: Btw. osgi:service hints that you use spring-dm. This is completely deprecated. You should switch to blueprint.

Comment: @ChristianSchneider,i tried with blueprint also but getting same error.i also check camel-servlet bundle showing in active state but somehow servlet component not found

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the feature that implements the camel component at runtime:

```
feature:install camel-servlet
```